# What is the physical screen size of an iPhone X in millimeter?

Tags: iphone

Apple only tells us the physical size of the iPhone X body which is 143.6mm x 70.9mm. In comparison, we know the screen size of the iPhone 8 is 104mm x 58mm. iPhone X and iPhone 8 shares almost the same physical screen width, with only a few millimeters apart. But the question is what is the physical screen width and height of an iPhone X in millimeter?

Answer (score 0):

Given the measurement found [here](https://www.apple.com/lae/iphone-x/specs/), the height should be 130.6068mm and the width 67.1 mm. However since I couldn't find the height of the top and bottom rim areas that surround the screen, the calculation is not exact.